# Definition of S-reducibility and reducibility of a space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

I was going through [this](https://jkms.kms.or.kr/journal/view.html?doi=10.4134/JKMS.2012.49.2.251) paper by Tanaka but I am stuck at Proposition 4.1 given below [image]. I just cannot make sense of the first two lines of the proof. What does it mean when he says S-reducible and reducible? I tried searching online also but could not find anything, nor does the author refer to anything.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks and regards in advance.

Comment: I've never heard that term, but given the context, could it just mean "the $n$-manifold $M$ is S-reducible if the identity of $S^n$ factors through $M$ up to homotopy"?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi If that's the case we need to see if the same is true for 3-dim projective space? What maps can we consider on and from sphere through the projective space

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An $n$-dimensional CW complex with a single $n$-cell is **reducible** if the projection $X \to X/X^{(n-1)} = S^n$ onto the top cell admits a section up to homotopy.  It is **stably reducible**, or **S-reducible**, if such a section exists for the associated suspension spectra.  An early use of this term is in

```
James, I. M.
Spaces associated with Stiefel manifolds.
Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) 9 (1959), 115–140.
```

The dual notions (**coreducible** and **S-coreducible**) appear in

```
Atiyah, M. F.
Thom complexes.
Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) 11 (1961), 291–310.
```

These ideas play a role in Adams' solution of the vector fields on spheres problem.

```
Adams, J. F.
Vector fields on spheres.
Ann. of Math. (2) 75 (1962), 603–632.
```

Comment: Can you explain " a section up to homotopy". @JohnRognes

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana Please consult the references I gave, or a textbook, such as Husemoller's "Fibre Bundles" or  Hatcher's "Algebraic topology".