# Reducibility and S-reducibility

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

This is in continuation to my previous [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/433878/126899). I clearly understand the definitions now and I went through the paper by James. But he only talks about the Reducibility of Stunted Projective spaces. Using which I could say that RP^n are not reducible. But I could not figure out the proof that he is giving, I don't get the following things.

1. Why is RP^3 S-reducible?
2. What is that map given in the next line, how does the surjectivity helps in reducibility?
3. And finally How we get the reducibility of Fifth Suspension of Rp^3?

kindly help me with these.

Any hints will be appreciated.

Regards

---